# How do create an instance of Fuel Email and use it?

Tags: php, fuelphp

Noob to Composer and packagist.

When I install, for example, Respect/Validation with Composer, it puts it into vendor/ directory, and I add the necessary 'use' statements, etc.

I keep referencing: https://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/email/usage.html

It doesn't tell me what to put at the top for the 'use' statement.
Also, when I run 'composer require fuel/email', I notice that, unlike other Composer packages, Fuel/email doesn't go into 'vendor' directory...why not?

Consequently, this crashes things:

```
$email = Email::forge();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Fuel/email doesn't go into 'vendor' directory...why not?

`fuel/email` is from same vendor of the framework, therefore library will go into **`fuel/packages/email`** directory. Just for double check, ensure that you `composer.json` file in root project directory includes `"fuel/email": "1.8.*",` in `require`.

> it puts it into vendor/ directory, and I add the necessary 'use' statements, etc.

This is unnecessary, because all vendor classes will be autoloaded by `vendor/autoload.php`, which is generated by composer.

> It doesn't tell me what to put at the top for the 'use' statement

Same as mentioned above you don't need to use `use` statement. However, you need to configure which packages to be loaded.

Therefore, you need to add `email` to `always_load` configuration of packages in `fuel/app/config/config.php` file, like below

```
/**************************************************************************/
/* Always Load                                                            */
/**************************************************************************/
'always_load'  => array(

    /**
     * These packages are loaded on Fuel's startup.
     * You can specify them in the following manner:
     *
     * array('auth'); // This will assume the packages are in PKGPATH
     *
     * // Use this format to specify the path to the package explicitly
     * array(
     *     array('auth' => PKGPATH.'auth/')
     * );
     */
    'packages'  => array(
        'email',
    ),
```

Comment: Wow! Makes sense. It's late now, but will be trying tomorrow. Tx.

Comment: Ok, just tried it out. Everything is good and follows what you *until* fuel/app/config/config.php.

Comment: I don't have that config.php. I made one and pasted what you had above. Does this mean that I have to actually do a Composer Require for the whole fuel framework just to use this email package? I guess I'll try that now...

Comment: I'm guessing that perhaps I'm just misusing fuel/email. Looking at it in Packagist, it seemed like a great simple solution for sending a mail out after the form data passed my validation (using Respect/Validation). 
Now, I guess Fuel is more for a 'full blown' PHP app, and it requires a 'full commitment.' It's not just another 'vendor' package to throw in and 'use'... :(

Comment: You're right. You need to be using fuelphp framework to use fuel/email. If you check type of fuel/email package, it is defined as fuel-package, not library.